# Clarification on "Every polynomial function of degree $\ge1$ has at least $1$ zero in the complex number system."

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra says "Every polynomial function of degree $\ge1$ has at least $1$ zero in the complex number system."

My question is, where do the rest of the zeroes of the polynomial lie? Can it happen that they do not belong to the complex number system? Would we then have to pass to a number system beyond the complex numbers?

Comment: All of the zeros lie in the complex numbers. The complex numbers are algebraically closed, meaning every polynomial with complex number coefficients of degree $n$ has $n$ zeros (counted with multiplicity), and can be fully factored as products of $(x-\lambda)$ factors where $\lambda$s are the zeros.

Comment: There is lot of stuff "beyond" the complex number, yet there is no non-trivial algebraic extension of  $\;\Bbb C\;$ .

Comment: Do we not count the quaternions as a "non-trivial algebraic extension of $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs No, because algebraic extensions are field extensions, in my opinion

Comment: "My question is, where do the rest of the zeroes of the polynomial lie"  All roots(zeroes) of the polynomial lie in the complex numbers and there are no other zeros that lie somewhere else.  The phrasing "at least one" is because polynomials of degree 1 (ax + b) will have only one root and polynomials with multiplicity roots (such as $(x - c)^n$) may have only one value of a multiple root. All roots, and there are at least one, are complex.

Comment: Related thought I had: "Is there a polynomial whose zeros are not covered by real and complex numbers.". The asker's premise assumes such a polynomial exists. I do not believe it does.

Comment: I mean, if you have a polynomial over a field that is not a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ you could have a polynomial with zeros not covered by real or complex numbers but that's probably not what you're asking. $\mathbb{C}$ is an algebraically closed field, which means any (non constant) polynomial with complex (which include real & rational) coefficients has all of its roots contained in $\mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 23):

The theorem may as well state that every polynomial equation of degree $n$ has *exactly* $n$ roots (counted with their multiplicity). The statements are equivalent, for, if your polynomial $p(z)$ of degree $n$ has one root $\lambda$, then you can factor it as

$$
p(z) = (z-\lambda)q(z),
$$
where the degree of $q$ is $n-1$ Then you can recursively apply the result to $q$, until you reach a polynomial of degree 1.

Answer (score 15):

This is a statement of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra that is completely correct, but in a way kind of obscures what is actually going on if someone doesn't think about what this actually means...

Consider a complex polynomial $p(z) = a_0 + a_1z + ... + a_nz^n$. By the fundamental theorem of algebra, this has at least 1 zero. It is a well-known result that when a polynomial has a zero at $r$ we can write:

$$p(z) = (z-r)(b_0 + ... + b_{n-1}z^{n-1}) = (z-r)(q(z))$$

for some polynomial $q(z)$ of degree $n-1$.

By the fundamental theorem of algebra we have that q(z) (as long as it is not constant) has at least 1 zero, so we factor that zero out and repeat until the degree of the not-yet-factored part (in this case, $q(z)$) is constant.
An induction argument can make this far more formal.

The confusion ensues because the zero of $q(z)$ can be the same as the zero of $p(z)$. So we could have that a degree $n$ polynomial $p(z)$ has only one (distinct) zero. For example $p(z) = (z+1)^n$. This polynomial only has 1 distinct zero, but it has multiplicty $n$.

But we can use the argument I had outlined above to phrase the fundamental theorem of algebra in a different way (or I've heard some people claim this is a corollary):

A nonconstant polynomial of degree $n$ has, counting multiplicity, exactly $n$ zeros.